# Why odd multiplicity roots cross x axis and even multiplicity "rebound"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to know the explanation of that behavior.

Comment: Because when $n$ is odd, $(x-r)^n$ changes sign as $x$ passes through $r$; it doesn't change sign when $n$ is even.